# How to call the view controller from another view controller programmatically depending on the response from the remote server

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

In my app I take the server credentials in the main view controller (loginViewController.swift). When I click on 'Login' button on the 'loginViewController', its shows the app logoViewController which has the activity indicator view and the credentials value is passed to the remote server over https connection. I get a JSON array in the response from remote server which consist of message "Successful : 1" or "Unsuccessful : 0" with other app details.

For the value '1' in the JSON array I want to show the menuViewController screen and for the value '0' I want to show the RegisterViewController screen for further process in the app.

Calling of 'menuViewController'/'RegisterViewController' should happen in the background process of the 'logoViewController'.

If have tried the following code given bellow, but unable to call the  'menuViewController'/'RegisterViewController'.

Please let me know were I went wrong. Is the UIStoryboard approach is right?
Any suggestion or links or tutorial will be helpful.

```
import UIKit

class logoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var act: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.act.startAnimating()



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // syncreq function is called from the connectionViewController.
    // connectionViewController is the common class for connecting to the remote server  
    func syncreq (JSONdata: AnyObject) { // Proceesing for PRMS response


       // Getting the value from the JSON
        var Successful = self.getIntFromJSON(JSONdata as NSDictionary, key: "Successful")


        println("Value of Successful : \(Successful)")

        if (Successful == 0){


            //let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registrationID") as regVC

            //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
            //performSegueWithIdentifier("registrationID", sender: self)


            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registrationID") as RegisterViewController
            self.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
        else if (Successful == 1){
             let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mnuID") as menuViewController
            self.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }



    }

    func getIntFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> Int {

        let info : AnyObject? = data[key]
        // println("Value of data[key] : \(key)")

        if let info = data[key] as? Int {
            println("Value of value for \(key) : \(info)")
            return info
        }

        else {
            return 0

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a common function that will callback the calling function on the response from the remote server.

Following is the function which I have implemented.

```
func connect(jsonString:NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary
{



            var JSONdata: AnyObject = ["" : ""] as Dictionary<String, String>

            println("------------------Function connserv")

            let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    var conn_timeout: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("conn_timeout")!
    var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    var number:NSNumber? = numberFormatter.numberFromString(conn_timeout as! String)
    if let number = number {
        var integer = Int(number)
        println("\(integer)")
    }
            var recon_maxcount: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("recon_maxcount")!
    println("recon_maxcount in Connection : \(recon_maxcount)")
    println("conn_timeout in Connection : \(conn_timeout)")
    var recon_interval: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("recon_interval")!
    println("recon_interval in Connection : \(recon_interval)")
    var number1:NSNumber? = numberFormatter.numberFromString(recon_maxcount as! String)
    if let number1 = number1 {
        var integer1 = Int(number1)
        println("\(integer1)")
    }
    var number2:NSNumber? = numberFormatter.numberFromString(recon_interval as! String)
    //if let number2 = number2 {
        var integer2 = Int(number2!)
    var xval = UInt32(integer2)
        println("\(xval)")
    //}

            var IP: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("IP")!
            var port: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("Port")!
            println("IP in Connection : \(IP)")
            println("port in Connection : \(port)")
            prefs.synchronize()

            println("HTTP request jsonString : \(jsonString)")

            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://\(IP):\(port)/")!)
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: nil, error: &error)
    request.timeoutInterval = (number as! NSTimeInterval)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-encoding")
    println("Firing synchronous url connection......")
    println(request)
          //println("Before======\(i)!")
    for (var i = 0; i < number1 as! Int ; i++)
    {
        var error: NSError?
        println("Try connecting to server: \(NSDate())")

        let urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
        //println("response : \(response)")
        //println("error : \(error)")

        if error != nil || urlData!.length == 0
        {
            println("Error happend timeout======\(error?.code)!")
            println(NSDate())

            sleep(xval as UInt32)
            //println("NSDate()")
            JSONdata = ["0" : "0"] as Dictionary<String, String>
            continue
        }
        else
        {
            println("Successfully connected : \(NSDate())")
            println("\(urlData!.length) bytes of data was returned")
            println(response!);
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                println("Status Code ------------------------------------>\(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }
            println(NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            var er: NSError?

            let JSONresdata: AnyObject = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers,error: &er)!)
             println("==========================================================================================")
            println("JSON response : \(JSONresdata)")
            JSONdata = JSONresdata as! NSDictionary
            break

        }
    }
     println("out of for loop : \(JSONdata)")
    return JSONdata as! NSDictionary;

}
```